# Parse API response with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, cloud9

I have got the response from the JSON API, but I don't know how to parse it, it just comes back with an error, I don't know enough about it to figure it out, it returns:

> (node:36308) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

```
var fetch = require('node-fetch');
fetch('https://sv443.net/jokeapi/v2/joke/Any', function(res){
    if (res.ok) {
        return res;
        } else {
        console.log(res.statusText);
    }
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then((json) => {
    var parsedData = JSON.parse(json)
    console.log(parsedData.joke);
});
```

Comment: seems like it's already a object try `json.joke`

Comment: You don't need `JSON.parse` - you already have [`res.json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json) which will give you an object.

Comment: yeah, but I'm trying to get the joke out of the JSON, how would I go around doing that?

Comment: `.json()` *parses the response body as JSON*. You already have an object.

Comment: oh yeah, nevermind me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to do the following to access the `delivery`.

```js
fetch("https://sv443.net/jokeapi/v2/joke/Any?type=single")
  .then(response => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(json => {
    // likely to be json.delivery but cannot 
    // confirm until rate limits have been lifted
    console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Comment: so, how do I get the objects inside the JSON, like print the joke and nothing else?

Comment: it returns undefined

Comment: there are rate limits so it is hard to confirm, but I think it should be just `json.delivery`.

Comment: it is returning undefined as you need to wait 60 secs as the rate limits have been exceeded

Comment: see updated answer, but yea, give it a couple of minutes

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
fetch('https://sv443.net/jokeapi/v2/joke/Any', function(res){
    if (res.ok) {
        return res;
        } else {
        console.log(res.statusText);
    }
})
.then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are already parsing it with res.json(). It returns an object (in promise) which can be accessed directly. Depending on a type prop you may have different props to check for. For example twopart joke will have setup: question, and delivery: answer